# How to match \" but not "

Tags: regex

I want to match the strings inside random texts

`"quoted text"`

`"valid \" escaped quote"`

`"balanced \\\" quotes"`

But not the strings

`"\\\"`

`"text"with quote"`

Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DVe3Y4/6)

correct answer

```
^"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"$
```

Thanks for Reference!